# Can't select from Accounts in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, account

I am implementing a trigger to convert Lead records that have a status of 'Qualified'.

I was able to get a trigger working except it was creating new accounts for every lead converted, which we didn't want.  In the Lead record the account name is stored as a string in the Company field.  I want to select from accounts with `Account.Name = Lead.Company` so I can get the `Account.ID` and use the `setAccountID()` function to avoid creating new accounts.

What I have so far:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [
        select MasterLabel
        from LeadStatus
        where IsConverted = true
        limit 1
    ];

    List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for(Lead tLead : Trigger.new) {
        String accName = tLead.Company;

        Account accountId = [
            select Id from 
            Account where Account.Name = ':accName' and Account_External_Id__c != null 
            limit 1
        ];
        // and Account_External_Id__c != null
        if((!tLead.isConverted && tLead.Status== convertStatus.MasterLabel)) {
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            //String oppName = lead.Name;
            lc.setAccountId(accountId.Id);
            lc.setLeadId(tLead.Id);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

            leadConverts.add(lc);
        }
    }
    If(!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts); //convert the leads
    }
}
```

No matter what I try the select from Accounts gives me a fatal error:

> FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

... And returns no records. I know there are records in the Account object for the Company name, I've even tried hard coding values into the query.

Comment: This trigger is not bulkified, you may think that only 1 Lead will ever be converted per transaction but SFDC supports bulk Lead Conversion through APIs and Apex.  best to get in the habit of bulkifying all triggers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
Account.Name = ':accName'
```

to this:

```
Name = :accName
```

so your entire query would be:

```
Account accountId = [
      SELECT Id, Name FROM 
      Account WHERE Name = :accName AND Account_External_Id__c != null 
      LIMIT 1
  ];
```

saying `= ':accName'` is looking for Accounts with the literal value ":accName" since you wrapped it in single quotes. You don't need single quotes around SOQL bind variables.

You should not have this SOQL query within your for loop - please see [Apex best practices.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) For every iteration of your loop, you will accrue a SOQL query - this will quickly hit governor limits in any type of bulk scenario.

Comment: I changed it to where Name = :accName but it's still not returning anything and I get the same error message

Comment: Beat me to it! Does it work @Cory?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not returning any records...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33037/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-mansfield-cant-select-from-accounts-in-trigger).